# variable changes to list<T>

Tags: c#, list

So i am new to c# and have therefore never really used list before. I've gotten many good things out of it so far, but i've hit one snag.

```
public static List<player> data(string ply, int val)
    {
        string rtn = "-";
        List<player> playerdata = new List<player>()
        {
            new player() { plr = "player1", name = "pl A", one = 0, two = 0, twopair = 0 },
            new player() { plr = "player2", name = "pl B", one = 0, two = 0, twopair = 1 }
        };

        var game = playerdata.Where(p => p.plr == ply);

        foreach (var player in game)
        {
            player.one = val; //This is where my problem is
            rtn = player.name;
        }
        return playerdata;
    }
```

So under foreach, with the player.et = val; .. That works fine. But i would really like to be able to have "player.et" as a dynamic input. So i could send

```
data(string ply, int val, SOMETHING HERE)
```

linked to

```
foreach (var player in game)
    {
        SOMETHING HERE = val;
        rtn = player.name;
    }
```

How do i do that?

Thanks, in advance :D

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Can you edit your question and elaborate a bit what you're trying to do with the list? Your current code won't build at this point based on what you posted, so it's hard to tell what you're looking for.

Comment: Well, you could add another parameter to the method.  This doesn't make much sense though.  You'd over-write the value with every iteration of the loop, so only the last assignment would stick.

Comment: In the case you're describing you'd have a `ref` parameter, but why would something calling your method with both `SOMETHING HERE` and `val` in order to assign `val` to `SOMETHING HERE` not do so itself without passing `ref` parameters? FYI, `ref`s are evil: http://blog.devbot.net/conventions-refs/

Comment: This is just a part of the hole code. What i just need to find is a viable way to choose what data i change in the list. So can send value and where to put that value to a method. I send to date what player to look for. so ply will be lets say "Player1" and then val could be 25. i can then through code put Player.one = val; (sry i can see i have put in player.et) but i need a way to make the ONE in player.one to be viable.

Comment: Yes. There are two ways. You can either use a delegate, or reflection. Preferable the former. `public static List<Player> Data(string ply, int val, Action<Player, int> assignValue){ foreach (var player in  game) { assignValue(player, int); }}` You could then call this code using lambda: `var players = Data("foo", 12, (player, value) => player.et = value)`

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for but you could use `dynamic` type

Comment: It is supposed to be a variable version of player.ONE. I have one, two and two pair. But only one value input at a time. So need to be able to tell my method what player, what value but also where to put the value. so instead of putting in player.ONE = val; or player.TWO = val; or player.TWOPAIR = val; -- i could then instead put in some sort of variable like player.X = val; where X was then a variable i had send to data through data(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
public static List<player> data(string ply, string property, int val)
{
    string rtn = "-";

    List<player> playerdata = new List<player>()
    {
        new player() { plr = "player1", name = "pl A", one = 0, two = 0, twopair = 0 },
        new player() { plr = "player2", name = "pl B", one = 0, two = 0, twopair = 1 }
    };

    playerdata.Where(p => p.plr == ply).ToList().ForEach(p => {
        var propInfo = p.GetType().GetProperty(property);
        if (propInfo != null)
            propInfo.SetValue(p, val, null);
        rtn = p.name;
    });

    return playerdata;
}
```

Comment: yeah, i would just like it without all the ifs. Lets say i had 60 input possibilitys , then it would be a bit daft. So what i want is that the part after the p. becomes dynamic.

Comment: @Hudlommen How about this?

Comment: Cool, glad I could help ;).